# Infinite loop java / events in java for a plugin MC

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I've a problem with a plugin for MC and I need an infinite loop which await the condition to be satisfiated. But it create an infinite loop but the variable have changed. Here is the code :

```
boolean bState;
public boolean GetState(){
    return bState;
}
public void SetState(boolean bState) {
    this.bState = bState;
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (event.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) && event.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.CHEST && event.getItem().getType() == Material.DIAMOND_SWORD)  {
        Chest chest = (Chest) event.getClickedBlock().getState();
        event.setCancelled(true);
        Inventory inv = chest.getInventory();
        inv.getContents();
        Inventory sinv = Bukkit.createInventory(player, chest.getInventory().getSize());
        sinv.setContents(inv.getContents());
        SetState(false);
        player.openInventory(sinv);
        while(GetState() == false){
            getLogger().info("Ok");
        }
        //Some other things to do
    }
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerCloseInv(InventoryCloseEvent event) {
    Player player = (Player) event.getPlayer();
    SetState(true);
}
```

I'm sure at 100% that the event onPlayerCloseInv is triggered after onPlayerInteract. Can anyone help me ? 
Thank you :D

EDIT: 
With my new code onPlayerCloseInv doesn't start anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bukkit, you have the principle of a single main thread only.

Because this thread can only do 1 thing at a time, you cannot use spinlocks to wait for conditions, as a spinlock essentially keeps the thread busy.

## Moving the close code to the `setState`

While this is the easiest method, using the will, you will lose track of your local variables.

```
public void SetState(boolean bState) {
    if(this.bState == false && bState == true) {
        //Some other things to do
        getLogger().info('Inventory closed');
    }
    this.bState = bState;
}
```

## Using a local runnable for the negative state

While this method suffers of the penalty of a new lamba instance, and a slightly more obfuscated stack trace, it offers benefit in the fact that using this, you have access to all your local (implied) final variables.

```
Runnable closeTask = null;
public void SetState(boolean bState) {
    if(this.bState == false && bState == true ) {
        if(closeTask != null) {
            closeTask.run();
            closeTask = null;
        }
    }
    this.bState = bState;
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (event.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) && event.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.CHEST && event.getItem().getType() == Material.DIAMOND_SWORD)  {
        ...
        player.openInventory(sinv);
        closeTask = () => {
            //Some other things to do
             getLogger().info('Inventory closed');
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but Eclipse doesn't recognize ``closeTask = () => {
            //Some other things to do
             getLogger().info('Inventory closed');
        }; `` Is it normal ?

Comment: that is java 8 syntax, replace it with `closeTask = new Runnable(){@Override public void run(){ /*Some other things to do*/ }}` for java 7

Comment: Less Java 8 syntax and more "that's a lambda function." Lambda functions were added to Java 8 (but exist elsewhere too).